what determines whether an empty string will appear at the beginning of the result when using re.split()?
Let's say I use re.split("[ ]+","  a  b  c  "), where there are several spaces at the beginning, end of the string and between the words, why if I use just [ ]+ pattern, the result will be [",'a','b','c',"], but if I use a pattern where there is more than one character in parentheses (several spaces or ,!?, etc.), then empty strings do not appear? But at the same time, if there is only one space at the beginning, then an empty string does not appear at all?
For the [ ]+ pattern, I expected to get just a list of words without spaces, because using such a pattern for a string where there is only one space at the beginning/end, there are no spaces in the result list, however, when there are several spaces in the beginning of the string, empty string appear. After that, I used [ ,.?!]+ and [  ]+ (two spaces), expecting the same result, but in this case it doesn't matter how many spaces are at the beginning/end of the string, there are no empty string in the result list

Can you provide a specific example where the result is ('a', 'b', 'c'), rather than ('', 'a', 'b', 'c', '')? (Varying the regular expression, not the string.)

well I guess ' ' is part of the split solution if there are enough blanks to be split by blankspace.Also [ ] is a not ideal supplement for \s

print(re.findall("[^ ]"," a  b  c  ")) with just the additional ^ will give you the letters without the blanks

re.split() is similar to str.split() -- if the delimiter is at the beginning/end of the input, the result contains an empty string there. ',1,2,'.split(',') => ['', '1', '2', '']

The exception is when you use the default delimiter to split on any whitespace, then leading/trailing whitespace is ignored.
